# I cannot boot Ubuntu 22.04 after a dual system instalation with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

after some years without Ubuntu I´m comming back ;)
After write my problem I have tried to resolve looking for in everywhere but the information didn´t work for me.
I have a HP pavilion power, I have 1TB hard disk and I installed an SSD and I have installed Ubuntu and my problem is that I don´t have the dual boot option!
I will attach some photos to see the situation but I have read everything that I could and I have no results.
I have attached images.

EasyBDC Information

https://ibb.co/XZQXpxt
https://ibb.co/wz6s7H6
https://ibb.co/0KSbMmX

System Information

https://ibb.co/tZdqXtc

Bios Setup

https://ibb.co/tHJdXY7

The only way to star Ubuntu is pressing Shift and rebooting my computer.

https://ibb.co/M8qgY4M

Please If anybody has any idea I will be grateful!

Damián

PD: When I access to Ubuntu pressing Shift and restart I have the dual boot option. But I cannot configurate from the Bios to start with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I understand Ubuntu supports UEFI, but in some cases I have had to disable UEFI and use the legacy setup.

Every time I have followed the instructions from the Dell site, even when using an HP machine and it has worked except for the very latest ACER laptop when I had to find the "Secret" bios setting to bypass the security check.

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!! I will read that! ; )

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the photos, looks like your ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode. Did you install Windows after installing ubuntu?

you can try installing rEFind or re-installing grub, by booting into ubuntu (from the windows advanced restart section (the photo you attached))

or from a live ubuntu USB, try using boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer,I will try both options!

Comment: Hello! I have tried now because in the week was complecated.
I have this feedback of the program

Comment: You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Comment: I have tried to change the boot order but I couldn't

Comment: Could you please clarify this part of your answer: rEFind  Did you mean refind/bionic 0.11.2-1 amd64?

Comment: If this answer doesn't help, you may want to read up on what I call boot coups: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html Read, especially, the last two sections on that page. It could be that your firmware is buggy or your NVRAM is damaged, in which case the computer will ignore changes to the boot order to make GRUB the default boot program, in which case you'll need to juggle things around to bypass the Windows loader, at least as the first boot program.